# Is JRuby like RubyMRI but better, or are there some things it lacks?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am considering using JRuby in a project which would need to talk to some Java.

From what I am reading about JRuby I am not noticing that it is missing anything that the standard Ruby has.  Is that true?  Does JRuby have everything the original Ruby has and also the JVM on top of it?

Or is there something missing in JRuby and using it necessitates some benefit trade-off to some degree?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: The front page (of jruby.org) says, in big white letters, that it's "Ruby 1.8.7 compatible". What more do you want?

Comment: @delnan The devil is always in the details.  For example, can Ruby be run on Tomcat?  I know there are some Ruby libraries that can not be used with JRuby.  Also, the front page of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few [differences](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/DifferencesBetweenMriAndJruby). Notably, JRuby can only utilize pure-Ruby gems (so no "native" gems written partially in, e.g., C). Also, JRuby only has full support for Ruby 1.8.7 (so no Ruby 1.9.x).

Comment: Would the lack of Ruby 1.9 have a significant impact?  What are the core differences? - Thanks! :)

Comment: Also, is the syntax of Ruby and JRuby different?

Comment: @Genadinik if the syntax was different, it would not be Ruby.

Comment: @Genadinik: Re: the lack of Ruby 1.9 compatibility, I guess it's only an issue if you're dead-set on using Ruby 1.9-only features.

Comment: JRuby 1.6.1 has "very high" compatibility with Ruby 1.9.2. The release also includes "experimental" support for native gems. (via http://jruby.org) If you have specific requirements, visit their very friendly IRC channel or check on the wiki: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Ruby1_9Support